# IOS - When tapped on a tab item, I need to check condition to show other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

In my app, I have UITabBarController, when user tapped on a tabbar item (e.g: tab index is 3), I want to check one condition (if...) to show different ViewController.

So my question is where to implement this condition function?

Comment: if you want this type of condition so u can apply tab bar segue using programmatic

Comment: Darji Jigar, I think so. Where can I add check method to show view controller when tapped TabBarItem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the delegate of the `UITabBarController` as below:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewController is TabBarDelegate {
        let v = viewController as! TabBarDelegate
        v.didSelectTab(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with create tabbar by button and view is a scrollview